# Magento 1.9.3 - PayPal Payments Pro Hosted - PSD2

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

Hope someone can let me know more info about using PayPal Payments Pro Hosted solution on Magento 1.9.3 for the PSD2 directive (3DS).

Currently when I am using the PayPal Payments Pro Hosted solution and the iFrame loads at the checkout page - I do not see any 3DS fields and I don't seem to see any configuration fields for it in the config.

Is it not active yet because it only comes into effect in Sept?
At which point it will appear?

Or do I need a new PayPal pro module for Magento?

Here's what PayPal say:

https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/psd2

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I have the same question

Comment: Nope - didn't get anything from anyone. Guess I'll have to ask PayPal